# Automate transpiling entire Dart project into single file?

Tags: dart, dart2js

I'm new to Dart and trying to understand the JavaScript compilation process. After doing to reading, I can't seem to find a way to automatically build an entire project of Dart files at once. Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you run the generate javascript command on any dart project with a main method, all code required by the project in question is automatically compiled to the javascript output file.